# if else loop for post count 0 and >0 with div

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I've got the following, which is correctly displaying the response ("1 responses to this piece") when there are child posts. When there are no child posts, I need it to remove the div with the h3 tag "responses to this piece". It shows up as a paragraph in the previous div. Any thoughts?

I've tried to add an ifelse statement where have_posts() = 0). So far, this has not worked.

```
                <div>
                <?php if ($count = $child_query->have_posts() > 0) 
                     { ?>
                        <div class="responses-to-piece lemonde"><h3>
                        <?php echo $count; 'Responses to this piece';}
                    ?> Responses to this piece</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<div>
                <?php 
                $count = $child_query->have_posts();
                if ($count > 0) 
                {
                    echo '<div class="responses-to-piece lemonde"><h3>'; echo $count; echo ' Responses to this piece</h3></div>';
                }
                else
                { 
                  echo 'No Responses to this piece';
                }
                ?> 
</div>
```

Just for disambiguation sake...

Because maybe the operation is evaluated as `$count = ($child_query->have_posts() > 0)` and not `($count = $child_query->have_posts()) > 0`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it changed nothing. Same results.